# Check if multiple perl versions are installed on machine

Tags: c#, perl

Our applications run with Strawberry Perl, and if any other Perl (Active Perl) version is installed our application won't work. Is there any way to check if multiple Perl (Strawberry, Active) versions are installed on the machine?

Comment: you need script or way to checking manually?

Comment: Why doesn't the application work in Active Perl?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5256901/1030675

Comment: I think the better answer would be to check _why_ it doesn't work. `perl` is supposed to be portable - my best guess would be missing default libraries, which is best checked with a `perl -e 'require ....'` type option.

Comment: I need an script to check multiple Perl installations.

Comment: What have you attempted so far, and why didn't it work? What happens when your application is run under AcrivePerl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will tell you how many versions of perl are in the PATH directories

```
perl -E '@p = `which -a perl`; printf "%d copies of perl in the path\n", 0+@p'
```

#### output

```
2 copies of perl in the path
```

Comment: Above command works for Linux environment.

Comment: perl -e "print $^X" command prints Perl paths on Windows.

Comment: @Pradeep: Rather than commenting on my answer, it would have helped us to give you better answers if you had answered some of the questions above. We can't know the details of what you're trying to do if you won't tell us. I wrote this answer in exasperation as it seemed like we weren't going to get any more information. It was a wild guess that may help someone.